# Switching focus between NERDTree view and file view

Tags: macos, macvim, nerdtree

I'm trying to map alt left/right to move the cursor focus between the file window and the NERDTree window. I've tried remapping ctrl-w-w but I just can't get it to work right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following to your ~/.gvimrc

```
map <A-Right> <C-W>l
map <A-Left> <C-W>h
```

This will work with the GUI, but not in the terminal.